# How to compare 2D distributions?

Tags: python, scipy, entropy

I need to compare 2D distributions with KL Divergence. I tried using `scipy.stats.entropy` but that's returning `inf`.

How do I set up `scipy.stats.entropy` to work with 2 axes and return a value?

I tried:

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
import pandas as pd

one = pd.read_csv(file_one)
two = pd.read_csv(file_two)
pk = [list(item) for item in zip(one["X"], one["Y"])]
qk = [list(item) for item in zip(two["X"], two["Y"])]
for l in [pk, qk]:
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            # to confirm that no values are 0 
            #(will change to a smaller value once inf is not being returned)
            if abs(l[i][j]) < 0.1:
                l[i][j] = 0.1
print(entropy(pk, qk))
```

That prints: `[inf inf]`

What I really want is a single value, but to start I need it to stop returning `ing`

Comment: Can you print the range of `pk` and `qk`? Based on the equations  in the documentation neither value can be negative. Also check whether you have any nans.

Comment: There are negative values in the data.  If I shift all values to become positive will that affect the outcome?

Comment: If you have negative values then you don't actually have a probability distribution and the test will fail...

Comment: why dont you just flatten the distributions in the same manner and use this as input to some KL Divergence function?

Comment: I've been trying coordinates from data which is completely off.  I'm going to use a histogram now which will actually be probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the equation for KL Divergence:

```
S = sum(pk * log(pk / qk), axis=0)
```

If you have zero values in qk this will result in your infinities. Since KL is a probability density (even a discrete one) probabilities of an event in a distribution are never zero, so you should replace your zeros with very small values. As for your shape issue, you could flatten the input or take a histogram.

Edit:
You can't have negative values either, what is a negative probability? KL divergence compares *distributions of probabilities* it isn't defined otherwise.

Comment: I converted 0's to small values `if abs(l[i][j]) < 0.1: l[i][j] = 0.1`.  The problem is negative values